# Miss two vertices on PolygonShape object

Tags: java, box2d

I've some trouble with PolygonShape object box2D.
I've 8 vertices drawing code:

```
float scaleW = width/12;
float scaleH = height/2;
chassisShape.set(new float[] {-scaleW*2,scaleH,  scaleW*2,scaleH,  scaleW*3,0,      scaleW*7,0,  scaleW*7,-scaleH,  -scaleW*5,-scaleH,  -scaleW*5,0,  -scaleW*3,0});
```

But this render an 6 vertices polygon only.
Where is the 2 missing vertices?

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVhJT.png

Maybe i've made an error, but I verified many time and I don't see what happen.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
Thanks for your help.
Maybe I didn't understand what is convex polygon, because I was pretty sure that was convex:

Screen of my prototype: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRIHN.png

So if I respect this skeleton, were is my error in my code? (counter-clockwise? or this is not convex too?)

EDIT2: Okay I just see that: if the angle is bigger than 180°, it's concave, so I have to change the shape for be simple than a triangulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polygon must be convex, and that one is not. Ideally it should also be wound counter-clockwise, and that one is not.

[image]

In situations like this Box2D will use the convex hull of the vertices given, which is why you ended up with a six sided polygon.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a Delaunay-triangulation (manually or with some algorithm).

Most render frameworks (Box2d, OpenGL,...) explicitly state that the given polygon should be convex (i.e. containing no notch.